# Book recommendation request

Tags: resource-recommendations, history

I've searched for a physics book with a historical approach but failed to find an appropriate one. I mean not only about the history & evolution of physics but also with all the mathematical details like an ordinary physics book but with content order based on history (any new chapter you read contains more modern concepts). I'd be glad if you recommend a book with this property.